# translations of 楽にして?

Tags: grammar, translation

How can I translate "楽にして" ? I read it change if transitive or intransitive...

The sentence was: 私が楽にしてやろう！

the context is: a guy asks to another about "being friends", but the other doesn't accept, the other guy is evil. The evil guy says that sentence before starting to control the good guy's mind.

can be "I'll make it easy (to you become my friend)?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

私が楽にしてやろう！ can mean a few things without further context.

The meaning that Japanese-learners would be most unfamiliar with is, believe it or not, "I will kill you/him/her."

Other meanings include:

"I will help/make you (or someone) feel better."

"I will cure your desease (or injury)."

It all depends on the context.  One of the above may or may not apply.  If not, please provide more context.

Comment: Some possible starting points for understanding/translation of the "kill" meaning: "I will [ease]/[free you from] your burdens (by killing you, taking control of your mind so you don't have to think any more, etc)" "Let me make things easy for you..."